# Passing string value to next view controller in a storyboard

Tags: ios, nsstring, segue

This should be fairly simple but for some reason for the last hour I have not been able to figure this out.

I am setting storing data in a string within **viewcontrollerA**

```
NSString *TestA = nameTextField.text;
NSLog(@"Output1 %@", TestA);
```

In **viewcontrollerB** I have set

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *TestA;
```

I know I should be using the below method to pass the string accros the storyboard but I cannot figure it out.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Sorry for the simple question.

Comment: @MicRO I did but couldn't get the examples working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    viewcontrollerB *secView = [segue destinationViewController]
    secView. TestA = nameTextField.text;

}
```

and please do some research on [Cocoa Code Naming Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002226), will help.